# Google Tag Assistant asks feed ID

Tags: google-ads-api, gtag.js

I was asked to upgrade an existing site from using the old remarketing tracking code that looked like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var google_conversion_id = 12345;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params; // this is empty
var google_remarketing_only = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/12345/?value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

to another method that looks like this:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-12345"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'AW-12345');
</script>
```

because it is asynchronous and should not block page loading. But the Google Tag Assistant extension that validates that tracking is set up correctly asks me to enter a "feed ID" when using the newer (gtag.js based) method. Previously it was showing Remarketing Tag as green.

Why is it needed now and not with the old code? I asked someone who has access to the AdWords account and they don't have the feed ID (or can't find it...).

I verified that the request to `googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/` is sent though devtools as described in Verifiction using browser based developer tools:

https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/verification

Is my configuration correct?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feed ID is related to dynamic remarketing campaigns.   If you aren't running a dynamic campaign, then the feed ID shouldn't matter.

That field to enter a feed ID is there to help you with validating that your feed is working correctly.

Here is a quick video that might help clear up your questions.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuOUNIFo0aQ

Comment: The video doesn't actually tell you where to get the Feed ID from though!

Comment: Nowhere tells what is "Feed ID". This string is there by mistake. If you see other versions of the "Tag Assistant" you can see that this text changes over time. But the value you must put in there is the merchant center "account-ID".