# How to get a feed ID for the Google ads remarketing tag?

Tags: google-ads-api, gtag.js

I've just installed some Google adwords code, and the tag assistant is flagging that I should 'enter the feed ID'. I'm struggling to figure out what a feed ID is/where to get one.

I watched the [Video on validation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuOUNIFo0aQ), but again it just seems to tell you to show you how to enter the ID once you have it without any indication of where you get it.

I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437434/3210927) to a similar question, but I'm still missing something about how to get the feed ID - even if it's functionally irrelevant, it would be nice to get the green light from the tag assistant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the id by logging into your AdWords account.   Click on tools in the top nav bar.   Then click on linked accounts.   Look for Google Merchant Center in the list.   Click on that.   You should be able to find your ID in there.